# In spark or spark streaming, how to configure log4j properities so that no too much logs are printing in the console?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

When I try to run a spark streaming program, there is too much logs printed out in the console. Can you recommend a good configuration so I can get only helpful in formation only?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `conf/log4j.properties` to suit your needs.

You most likely just want to change

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

to

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```

Comment: I tried changing the conf/log4j.properties, but it doesn't change anything. Is there any execution command I should use to apply the properites file?

Comment: How are you executing the job?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and changed the log4j.properties as indicated. the output then turned into this :D

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2015-11-06 00:13:05
-------------------------------------------
()
15/11/06 00:13:06 WARN BlockManager: Block input-0-1446768785800 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2015-11-06 00:13:10
-------------------------------------------
(u'hello', 1)
()
15/11/06 00:13:14 WARN BlockManager: Block input-0-1446768794000 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2015-11-06 00:13:15
-------------------------------------------
(u'', 1)
(u'you', 2)
(u'how', 1)
(u'are', 1)
()
```

looks great :D thanks